# python curve_fit doesn't work with stiff model

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to find the `x0`parameter which fits as much as possible the blue model on the green curve (`x0`control the width of the crenel; see below).

[image]

Here is my attempt:

```
from pylab import *
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x=linspace(0,2*pi,1000)    
def crenel(x):return sign(sin(x))
def inverter(x,x0): return (crenel(x-x0)+crenel(x+x0))/2

p,e = curve_fit(inverter,x,sin(x),1)    
plot(x,inverter(x,*p),x,sin(x))
ylim(-1.5,1.5)
```

By hand, the optimal value is `x0 = arcsin(1/2) # 0.523598`, but curve_fit doesn't estimate any value ( *"OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated"*) . I suspect the stiffness of the model. The [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) inform :

> The algorithm uses the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm through leastsq. Additional keyword arguments are passed directly to that algorithm.

So my question is : Is there keyword arguments that can help `curve_fit` to estimate the parameter in this case ? or another approach ?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Just curious, what happens when you pick a starting param thats closer to the optimal value?

Comment: Nothing :( .  It' seems that curve_fit is idle in this case.

Comment: hmm, dunno, what you've got looks like it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the objective function that `curve_fit` tries to minimize is not continuous.  `x0` controls the location of the discontinuities in the `inverter` function.  When a discontinuity crosses one of the grid points in `x`, there is a jump in the objective function.  Between these points, the objective function is constant.  `curve_fit` (actually, `leastsq`, the function used by `curve_fit`) is not designed to handle such a function.

The following function `sse` is (in effect) the function that `curve_fit` tries to minimize, with `x` being the same `x` defined in your example, and `y = sin(x)`:

```
def sse(x0, x, y):
    f = inverter(x, x0)
    diff = y - f
    s = (diff**2).sum()
    return s
```

If you plot this function on a fine grid with code such as

```
xx = np.linspace(0, 1, 10000)
yy = [sse(x0, x, y) for x0 in xx]
plot(xx, yy)
```

and zoom in, you'll see

[image: plot]

---

To use `scipy` to find your optimal value, you can use `fmin` with a smooth objective function.  For example, here's the continuous objective function, using only the interval [0, pi/2] (`quad` is `scipy.integrate.quad`):

```
def func(x0):
    s0, e0 = quad(lambda x: np.sin(x)**2, 0, x0)
    s1, e0 = quad(lambda x: (1 - np.sin(x))**2, x0, 0.5*np.pi)
    return s0 + s1
```

`scipy.optimize.fmin` can be used to find the minimum of that function, as in this snippet from an ipython session:

```
In [202]: fmin(func, 0.3, xtol=1e-8)
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.100545
         Iterations: 28
         Function evaluations: 56
Out[202]: array([ 0.52359878])

In [203]: np.arcsin(0.5)
Out[203]: 0.52359877559829882
```

Comment: Thanks for this work : I realize that the jacobian of the model is zero almost everywhere. but I think there is another problem here : 
`def inverter2(x,x0,A) : return A*convolve(inverter(x,x0),exp(-((x-pi)/.5)**2),'same')` is a smooth inverter that can't be manage with curve_fit too.